# AWS SQS Ports Requirement

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

AWS Documentation: 
"Amazon SQS supports the HTTP over SSL (HTTPS) and Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocols. Most clients can automatically negotiate to use newer versions of TLS without any code or configuration change. Amazon SQS supports versions 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 of the Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol in all regions."

Am I correct in assuming if you are using the AWs SQS SDK (java) then it is connecting to the AWS server on port 443  as it is HTTPS.

If not I can't find any pages that list required open ports.
So the question is what outbound ports are required for AWS SQS to function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you take a look at [the SQS endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#sqs_region) you'll see that only HTTP and HTTPS are supported.  HTTPS is documented as the default.  From the Java [Protocol Javadocs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/Protocol.html):

> Communication over HTTPS is the default, and is more secure than HTTP,
>   which is why AWS recommends using HTTPS. HTTPS connections can use
>   more system resources because of the extra work to encrypt network
>   traffic, so the option to use HTTP is available in case users need it.

Therefore, only port 443 is required unless you have very specific setup that requires HTTP (port 80).